# How to repeat a task in Azure Devops pipelines until i get a certain result?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating an Azure pipeline (via classic/web mode, not using yaml) to start a scan in Netsparker.
The call task is simple, but then I need another task to keep calling a method to check the scan status. Problem is that I need to keep repeating this task from time to time until the scan is finished. I don't know how many times, i just know that the output must be different than "In Progress" in order to fail the pipeline or move to another task.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do something like this?

I am afraid that there is no such method could repeat a task until get the certain result in Azure Devops Pipelines(classic mode/yaml mode).

In Azure Devops, you could run task multiple times via adding more tasks, but it doesn't support repeated running of a single task.

**A workaround:**

If you are using script to call the method(e.g. Powershell task), you could write the loop in the script:

For example:

```
do
{
    # Poll external process to see if it is done
    $Result = Invoke-RestMethod ...
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $WaitBetweenPolling.Seconds
}
while (($Result -eq "IN_PROGRESS") -and ((Get-Date) -lt $Timeout))

if ($Result -ne "SUCCESS")
{
    exit 1
}
```

On the other hand, I suggest that you could create a suggestion ticket in [Our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report this feature.

Comment: Oh thanks, this solved the problem for me.
I am indeed using a powershell script, but i didn't think of creating a loop inside the script to check the status. 
In the end, it became something like this:

$isScanCompleted = $scanStatus -eq [ScanTaskState]::Complete
  
      if ($isScanCompleted -eq $true) {
        Write-Output('Scan completed.')
        exit 0
      } else {
        Start-Sleep -s 600
      }

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a gate. The gate allows you to retry until success is met.

Look for the lightning bolt at the front of your stage.